# Working Hours Excel Formula

Tags: excel

I need to calculate the working hours elapsed between two dates and times, for example:

> Holiday taken between 01/09/2014 and 05/09/2014
>
> 5 working days @ 8 hours per day.

I need the result to show me how many working hours that would be. For example:

ANNUAL ENTITLEMENT: 89.9 Hours

```
DATE FROM  DATE TO    RETURN TO WORK HOURS REQUIRED HOURS REMAINING DATE
01/09/2014 05/09/2014 06/09/2014       40                49.90
```

I have no idea if this is even possible!

Comment: Try something like this (mathematic formula) : `(Day2 - Day1)*8`. You just have to find how to get the day from the date. Try some stuff in excel, you will find out easily (no VBA needed, only InCell excel commands).

Comment: Do you want to support fractional days?

Comment: I put this formula in but it returned 35.33 but I need it to return 40

Comment: We have 40 working hours in a week, it is for a holiday form for staff who have hourly calculated annual leave

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming these are given cells. if you type in the date to a cell you can click on a new cell and put uptop by the fx this

for example. In C1 you can type this into the fx. Make sure you put the equal sign.

```
=B1-A1
```

This is what is the dates in the cells
A1 = 1/9/2014
B1 = 5/9/2014

This will give you 120 which is the total days inbetween.
You will want to get the number of weeks so you can divide by 7. 
You will multiply weeks by number of days worked which is 5
Then you want the weeks times 8 hours you can do this in C1

```
=(B1 - A1)/7 * 5 * 8
```

which gives you 685.7143

Comment: In cell A1 I would have the start date 01/09/2014 in cell B1 would be the end date 05/09/2014. Staff work 08:00 - 16:30. So in cell C1 I need it to show me how many working hours there are between 01/09/2014 and 05/09/2014

Comment: I'm assuming they get a 30 minute lunch so it would be 8 total hours worked. I edited it and tried to put a better explanation from where the numbers were coming from.

Comment: Thanks, sorry I am from the UK so our dates are different, it would be 09/01/2014 - 09/05/2014. So it's 5 working days, 8 hours per day, does that make sense?

Comment: hmm.... that's strange. It does not work if you put the dates into UK format but it works fine if you have it in US format... it could be tedious but you could put the dates into us format.

Comment: I have used =(B1-A1+1)*8 and this has given me the answer I desire. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

you need to also take into account weekends which a simple subtraction will not do. Firstly find the total number of days:

```
TOTAL_NUMBER_DAYS = B1-A1 + 1
```

then calculate how many weekends:

```
TOTAL_WEEKENDS = WEEKNUM(B1) - WEEKNUM(A1)
```

finally take the total days and subtract weekends:

```
NET_TOTAL_DAYS = TOTAL_NUMBER_DAYS - (TOTAL_WEEKENDS * 2)

TOTAL_HOURS = NET_TOTAL_DAYS * 8
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this recently and had a working solution initially in Excel 2013. Slightly adapted to work in 2007 (lack of 'Days()' function). We use it for reporting on support tickets (length of time between opening and closing a ticket).

Inputs are "Workday start", "Workday end" from which "Hours worked" and "Hours not worked" are calulated.

Hours worked `=HOUR(WorkEnd-WorkStart)+(MINUTE(WorkEnd)+MINUTE(WorkStart))/60`
Hours not worked = 24 - Hours worked

Further inputs are a table ("Data") with first two columns "Open" and "Close", which are dateserial cells.

Next column is standard numeric value "Gross hours" `=(Data[[#This Row],[Close]]-Data[[#This Row],[Open]])*24`

Next column is standard numeric value "Net workdays" `=NETWORKDAYS(Data[[#This Row],[Open]],Data[[#This Row],[Close]])`

Next column is standard numeric value "Net days" `=MAX(1,DAY(Data[[#This Row],[Close]])-DAY(Data[[#This Row],[Open]]))`

Next column is standard numeric value "Gross workhours" `=IF(Data[[#This Row],[Gross hours]]>0,Data[[#This Row],[Gross hours]]-24*(Data[[#This Row],[Net days]]-Data[[#This Row],[Net workdays]]),0)`

Last column is standard numeric value "Total work hours" `=IF(Data[[#This Row],[Gross workhours]]<24,Data[[#This Row],[Gross workhours]],Data[[#This Row],[Gross workhours]]-(HoursNotWorked*Data[[#This Row],[Net workdays]]+HoursWorked))`

This solution makes it trivial to adjust start and end work times, as well as accounting for any holidays (via a small change to the NETWORKDAYS() function to utilise the optional parameter).